# When an MLE attains the Cramer-Rao bound for an exponential family.

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm trying to do the following exercise:

> Let $$\delta_\theta(x)=S(x)\exp (\theta T(x)-f(\theta))$$
>
> be a family of densities for a random variable $X:\Omega\rightarrow 
>  \mathbb{R}$, where $\theta$ takes values in an open interval, and
>   $T:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a non-constant function. 
>   Suppose the maximum likelihood estimator $\hat{\theta}(x)$ exists and has
>   finite variance for all $\theta$.  Prove that $\hat{\theta}(x)$ attains
>   the Cramer-Rao lower bound for all $\theta$ if and only if
>   $f'(\theta)$ has the form $\alpha \theta+\beta$ for constants $\alpha$
>   and $\beta$.

1. At present, all i know about the MLE $\hat\theta$ is that, for given $x\in \mathbb{R}$, it is the solution to $$f'(\hat\theta) = T(x) \label{a}\tag{1}$$
2. On its face, the question doesn't make much sense to me, since the book hasn't given me any information about the bias of $\hat{\theta}$.  So in principle, the Cramer-Rao lower bound $$Var(\hat{\theta})\geq \frac{[\frac{d}{d\theta}(\mathbb{E}_\theta[\hat{\theta}(x)])]^2}{\mathbb{E}_\theta[( \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\log \delta_\theta(x))^2]}$$ isn't really a lower bound, since the numerator depends on the estimator $\hat{\theta}$.  And the numerator could be zero, in principle.
3. Setting that aside, I think what the question wants me to do is just to write down the condition where the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality (used in the proof of the Cramer-Rao lower bound) gives equality:  We have $$\frac{d}{d\theta}\mathbb{E}_\theta[\hat \theta(x)]=\frac{d}{d\theta}\int_\mathbb{R}\hat \theta(x) \delta_\theta(x) ~~dx=\int_\mathbb{R}\hat \theta(x)~\cdot~\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \delta_\theta(x)~\cdot~\delta_\theta(x)^{-1}~\cdot~\delta_\theta(x)~~dx=$$

$$\int_\mathbb{R}(\hat \theta(x)-\mathbb{E}_\theta[\hat \theta])~\cdot~\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \delta_\theta(x)~\cdot~\delta_\theta(x)^{-1}~\cdot~\delta_\theta(x)~~dx ~~~\text{(since}\int_\mathbb{R}[\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \delta_\theta(x)]\delta_\theta(x)^{-1}\cdot~\delta_\theta(x)dx=0 \text{)}$$

$$= \int_\mathbb{R}(\hat \theta(x)-\mathbb{E}_\theta[\hat \theta])~\cdot~[T(x)-f'(\theta)]~\cdot~\delta_\theta(x)~~dx\leq \sqrt{\int_\mathbb{R}(\hat \theta(x)-\mathbb{E}_\theta[\hat \theta])^2~ \delta_\theta(x)~dx \cdot  \int_\mathbb{R}[T(x)-f'(\theta)]^2~\delta_\theta(x)~~dx}=$$

$$\sqrt{Var(\hat \theta) \cdot  \int_\mathbb{R}[T(x)-f'(\theta)]^2~\delta_\theta(x)~~dx}$$
   Whereas if we wanted equality we would need $$\hat \theta(x)-\mathbb{E}_\theta[\hat \theta]= C(\theta)\cdot[T(x)-f'(\theta)] $$ where $C(\theta)$ is a constant depending only on $\theta$. At this point I am totally stuck. And I haven't even used equation \ref{a}.

Answer (score 2):

To start with I'll assume that $\hat{\theta}$ is unbiased for $\theta$. I'll discuss the biased case at the end.

$\textbf{Claim}$ Let $l = \log(\delta_\theta(x))$. There exists an unbiased estimator $\hat{\theta}$, which attains the Cramér-Rao lower bound (under regularity conditions) if and only if
$$\frac{\partial l}{\partial \theta} = I(\theta)(\hat{\theta} - {\theta}).$$
I came across this statement and its proof in [these lecture notes by Jonathan Marchini](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~marchini/bs2a/lecture4_4up.pdf).

$\textbf{Proof}$ Let $U = \hat{\theta}$ and $V = \frac{\partial l}{\partial \theta}$. In the [proof of Cramér-Rao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound#Single-parameter_proof) we derive that
$$Cov(U, V)^2 \leq Var(U)Var(V).$$
We have equality here (and $\hat{\theta}$ attains the Cramér-Rao lower bound) if and only if $V = c_1 + c_2 U$. [We know that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound#Single-parameter_proof) $\mathbb{E}(V) = 0$, so $c_1 = -c_2 \mathbb{E}(U) = -c_2 \mathbb{E}(\hat{\theta}) = -c_2 \theta$. So $$V = \frac{\partial l}{\partial \theta} = c_2(\hat{\theta} - \theta).$$ Now we want to calculate $c_2$. If we multiply both sides by $\frac{\partial l}{\partial \theta}$ and then take expectations, we get
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\frac{\partial l}{\partial \theta}\right)^2\right] = c_2\mathbb{E}\left[\hat{\theta}\frac{\partial l}{\partial \theta}\right] - c_2\theta\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\partial l}{\partial \theta}\right].$$
The LHS equals $I(\theta)$, and the RHS equals
$$c_2 \int \hat{\theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left(\delta_\theta(x)\right) dx - c_2\theta \cdot 0 = c_2 \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta}\int\hat{\theta}\delta_\theta(x) dx = c_2 \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta}\mathbb{E}(\hat{\theta}) = c_2 \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta}\theta = c_2,$$
so the constant $c_2 = I(\theta)$. Therefore
$$\frac{\partial l}{\partial \theta} = I(\theta)(\hat{\theta} - \theta).\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$
Since
$$l = \log(S(x)) + \theta T(x) - f(\theta),$$
we have
$$\frac{\partial l}{\partial \theta} = T(x) - f^\prime(\theta).$$
At $\hat{\theta}$, $\frac{\partial l}{\partial \theta} = 0$ so
$$T(x) = f^\prime(\hat{\theta}).$$
We now calculate $\frac{\partial^2 l}{\partial \theta^2}$ in order to calculate the Fisher information:
$$\frac{\partial^2 l}{\partial \theta^2} = - f^{\prime\prime}(\theta).$$
The information $I(\theta)$ can be calculated as follows:
$$I(\theta) = \mathbb{E}\left[-\frac{\partial^2 l}{\partial \theta^2}\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[f^{\prime\prime}(\theta)\right] = f^{\prime\prime}(\theta).$$
Putting everything together, we have that $\hat{\theta}$ is an unbiased estimator for $\theta$ if and only if
$$f^\prime(\hat{\theta}) - f^\prime(\theta) = T(x) - f^\prime(\theta) = \frac{\partial l}{\partial \theta} = f^{\prime\prime}(\theta)(\hat{\theta} - \theta).$$

Now we want to solve this differential equation
$$f^\prime(y) - f^\prime(x) = f^{\prime\prime}(x) (y - x).$$
Let $g = f^\prime$. Then
$$g(y) - g(x) = g^{\prime}(x) (y - x).$$
This is bijective since $g^\prime$ is always strictly positive or negative. Making sure that $y \neq x$ we can then solve this:
$$\int\frac{1}{y - x} dx = \int \frac{g^\prime(x)}{g(y) - g(x)} dx$$
so
$$-\int \frac{d}{dx} (\log(y - x)) dx = - \int \frac{d}{dx} \log(g(y) - g(x)) dx$$
so
$$\log(y - x) + C = \log(g(y) - g(x))$$
so
$$\alpha(y - x) = g(y) - g(x)$$
so
$$g(x) = \alpha x + \beta = f^\prime(x).$$

Thinking about if the estimator is biased, we would replace the equation
$$\frac{\partial l}{\partial \theta} = f^{\prime\prime}(\theta)(\hat{\theta} - \theta)$$
with
$$\frac{\partial l}{\partial \theta} = f^{\prime\prime}(\theta)\frac{\hat{\theta} - \theta - b(\theta)}{1 + b^\prime(\theta)},$$
where $b(\theta)$ is the bias of $\hat{\theta}$, so I'm assuming that the differential equation has different solutions to $f^\prime(x) = \alpha x + b$.

Comment: Hey Alex, Thanks for your help.  Do you know what the author means at the bottom of the fifth slide when he says "not all MLE's attain the CRLB because not all MLE's are unbiased."?  Do you think its possible that when someone talks about an estimator achieving the CRLB, they automatically assume the estimator is unbiased?

Comment: Hey Tim, if the MLE is biased then it can't reach the $1/I(\theta)$ lower bound. A biased estimator can reach the $(1 + b^\prime(\theta))^2/I(\theta)$ lower bound as long as  $\frac{\partial l}{\partial \theta} = c_1 + c_2 \hat{\theta}$. For Marchini's statement to make sense, I think that he must be referring to the unbiased CRLB. I would guess that if someone wants to know if an estimator achieves the CRLB, they are talking about the unbiased version.

Comment: yep, your proof nails the unbiased cased (+1). The biased case is still a mystery to me. I've consulted with the author actually and he says unbiased is not required, so I'm stumped on that.    Btw, re: your last comment. can't b′(θ)<0? So if we call 1/I(θ) the CRLB, can't a biased estimator actually go below it?... its all very confusing

Comment: The variance of $\hat{\theta}$ can certainly be below $1/I(\theta)$ if $b^\prime(\theta) < 0$ (extreme example: if $\hat{\theta} = 0$ then $b(\theta) = -\theta$ and $Var(\hat{\theta}) = 0$).